# Why don't I need to bind my vertex buffer object before calling glDrawArrays?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm a bit confused why this still renders. I thought you need to bind a vertex buffer object so that glDrawArrays knows which vertex buffer to use.

Here is my initialisation code..

```
// Create and bind vertex array to store vertex attribute states.

glGenVertexArraysOES(NUM_VERTEX_ARRAYS, &m_vertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(m_vertexArray);

// Create and bind vertex buffer to store vertex data.

glGenBuffers(NUM_VERTEX_BUFFERS, &m_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * 36, &m_vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(VertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(VertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(VertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

Here is my render code. I'm confused why glDrawArrays still works when I bind 0 to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER.

```
glBindVertexArrayOES(m_vertexArray);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

Comment: This link gave me a better understanding on VAOs and VBOs.. http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2005.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought you need to bind a vertex buffer object so that glDrawArrays knows which vertex buffer to use.

When `glDraw…` is called it uses the data addressed to by the most recent calls to the `gl…Pointer` (or equivalent) calls and activated by `glEnableVertexAttribArray`. When you do

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBuffer);

glVertexAttribPointer(VertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glVertexAttribPointer(VertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
```

an association between the (active) vertex attributes and the buffer objects is formed. Or in other words: *`glBindBuffer` is only relevant for calls to `glBuffer…` **and** `gl…Pointer` calls.* Hence you can safely bind a different buffer object after making the call to a `gl…Pointer` function. In fact the following would work, too:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexPositionBuffer);    
glVertexAttribPointer(VertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexNormalBuffer);    
glVertexAttribPointer(VertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
```

i.e., different buffer objects are used for each vertex attribute array.

#### Update

Vertex Array Objects add some sugar coating to this, by making it possible to keep the bind→pointer/offset association in a object, that itself can be bound. So switching to a new (set of) buffer object(s) becomes less work.

Answer (score -1):

You're using vertex array objects, so all data is already recorded into VAO. Here is a good explanation of what data VAO holds http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2013/10/18/ios-open-gl-es-2-multiple-objects-at-once/

Comment: As I'm aware calls to glBindBuffer() don't get stored in the VAO. So wouldn't you need to call glBindBuffer() again after calling glBindVertexArrayOES()?

Comment: Not exactly that way. VAO stores buffer binding, but it actually doesn't matter in this case. The thing is how `glVertexAttribPointer` works - it sets attrib relative to currently bound buffer. It doesn't matter what you do later, attribute already set to buffer that _was_ active when it was called. As i recall, you can even set different attribs from different buffers at the same draw. So, when you binding VAO, it sets all attribtes arrays saved within it - no need to bind biffers. The only thing you can break this way is ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.

Comment: @keltar *"VAO stores buffer binding"* - No it doesn't, as you just explained that the buffer binding isn't required at all.

Comment: It does, but it is element array buffer, not vertex. And it matters, but not in case of `DrawArrays`

Comment: @valmo: It stores the buffer binding insofar as it stores vertex pointers, which are relative to whatever buffer was bound when they were setup. As far as the GL is concerned this is good enough to establish a dependency that will prevent the data store from being freed when the buffer is deleted, at least until the vertex pointer is changed.